# Are sleeping system R-ratings additive?

Tags: winter-camping, sleeping-pads

When buying a sleep system it is important to consider the R-rating, referring to the thermal resistance of the product(s) and how that compares to the conditions that one will use them in. Some people layer two or more sleeping mats/pads in order to use them at lower temperatures than they are rated for individually. Is the cumulative R-rating of a layered sleep system a simple addition of the R-ratings of the respective layers or is the correlation non-linear.

For example if I have a sleeping mat with an R-rating of 2 and a sleeping pad with an R-rating of 4, if I place the pad on top of the mat do I get an R-rating of 6 (as in 2+4) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do "R" values add proportionally](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/do-r-values-add-proportionally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they should be additive in this situation and its pretty commonly done.

> **As long as the materials involved are dense solids in direct mutual contact,[9] R-values are additive;** for example, the total R-value of an barrier composed of several layers of material is the sum of the R-values of the individual layers.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation))

> Yes, the R-values of sleeping pads are additive, provided that there is no air gap between them.

[Source](https://sectionhiker.com/new-sleeping-pad-r-value-standard-astm-ff3340/)